# Is there a way to add an editable block in ckeditor, which cannot be edited in the editor, but only in a dialog?

Tags: ckeditor, ckeditor4.x

I want to add a button to my ckeditor 4 where I can put some text or code, and it cannot be editable through the editor, but only in the dialog, and in the editor it will look like a block with edit\remove button or something similar.

Example:
[image: Example]

It's similar to how the galleries worked in Wordpress.

That's my function right now, which basically add a dialog and let me put some content in it and adding it to the ckeditor. but beyond that, I don't know what to do, and I would appreciate some help. maybe there's a plugin or something I can use? what do you suggest?

```
function showMyDialog(editor) {
    CKEDITOR.dialog.add('Good-list-gallery', function() {
      return {
        title: 'Good List',
        minWidth: 400,
        minHeight: 200,
        contents: [
          {
            id: 'tab-basic',
            label: 'Basic Settings',
            elements: [
              {
                type: 'textarea',
                id: 'goodListContent',
                label: 'Good List Content',
                setup: function(element) {
                  this.setValue(element.getText());
                },
                commit: function(element) {
                  element.setText(this.getValue());
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        ],
        onOk: function() {
          var goodListContent = this.getValueOf('tab-basic', 'goodListContent');
          var blockHtml = '<div class="non-editable-block">' + goodListContent + '</div>';
          editor.insertHtml(blockHtml);
        }
      };
    });

    editor.openDialog('Good-list-gallery');
  }
```